# In jquery, how to show ajax progress image without shift controls to the right over

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading, insertafter

i have a web page where there are 2 dropdowns next to each other.  when you change one dropdown i go to the server and update the value in the second dropdown.  Since this takes a few seconds, i have this code below that shows a ajax loading image while its waiting.

this issue is that since i am using insert after, when this runs, it pushes the second dropdown over a few pixels and when its complete, teh dropdown shifts back.

what is the best way to avoid this.  i somehow need to keep a placeholder with the same wdith as the image so when i show it, it keeps everying else from moving.

```
var spinner = $("<img src='/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif' />").insertAfter(item);

$.getJSON("/GetId/" + item.val(), function (data) {
    if (data.Id > 0) {
        $("#SecondDropdown").val(data.Id);
    }
    spinner.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

position:absolute on the spinner in a container above everything, is how I always do it.

```
<body>
    <div id='ajax_loader'></div>
    <div>
        <select name='1'>
            <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
            <option value='no'>No</option>
        </select>
        <select name='2'>
            <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
            <option value='no'>No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Basically put the div with the ajax loader first in your document and hide and show it as necessary.

Comment: can you clarify?  i don't fully follow your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery UI, you can use the `position` method to absolutely position the spinner relative to the dropdown:

```
var spinner = $('<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');

spinner.position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "right top",
    of: item,
    collision: "fit"
});

spinner.insertAfter(item);
```

Comment: Jquery UI is horribly bloated, boooooooooo Jquery UI.